# what's the meaning of this coredump?

Tags: gcc

got this coredump when the application started.

```
Core was generated by `/opt/SURGE/bin/SIM.run 0 0 1'.
Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error.
#0  0xf79d7ddb in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /opt/SURGE/lib/libTsdThreadedInput_ix86-linux-sles9-mt.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf79d7ddb in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /opt/SURGE/lib/libTsdThreadedInput_ix86-linux-sles9-mt.so
#1  0x32709808 in ?? ()
#2  0xeecb6414 in ?? ()
#3  0xeecb6418 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

what does it mean?
and where does the problem happen?

Comment: What version of GDB and what OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it is trying to access memory location at the address 0x00000000. but it is not saying which routine does that.

Comment: I just curious that what does '__gxx_personality_v0 ' mean?

Comment: i think it is a routine used to create the stack trace for the dump. you can find a lot of references to it on the web.

Comment: i do not mean that the stack trace is corrupted. i mean the name of this routine is there because it is called when stack trace is constructed when the error occurs. but the error is not because of this routine. it is because code tries to access a null pointer probably because your system does not have the right library installed or something else.